# Does the Decorator Pattern exist in the Java IO classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

For an assignment, I have to find out which of the Gang of Four design pattern the classes [`java.io.Reader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) and its subclasses [`java.io.PushbackReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html), [`java.io.BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [`java.io.FilterReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) were built with.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) post, the design pattern would be the Decorator Pattern. This only makes sense to me if `PushbackReader`, `BufferedReader` and `FilterReader` can be decorated to be used at the same time, creating effectively a `BufferedPushbackFilterReader`. Is that the idea?

Comment: Look at the constructors of those classes. Do they allow you to to stack, e.g.  the `Buffered ` nature on top of the `Filter` nature?

Comment: @Kilian Foth: Looks like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed decorate them like that. Just consider the following

```
PushbackReader pushbackBufferedReader = new PushbackReader(
     new BufferedReader(original));
```

That would decorate an original reader to

- first be buffered
- and then enable pushback/unread functionality (still the result is buffered..)

`FilterReader` and `Reader` are base classes in the hierarchy...

Comment: And `BufferedReader`, `FilterReader` and `PushbackReader` are decorators of `Reader`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Yes - BufferedReader make the underlying reader buffered, PushbackReader enables you to 'unread' data from the reader etc...

Answer (score 11):

The [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) applies here because `BufferedReader` wraps a `Reader` - it's still a `Reader` (it has all the methods of `Reader`), but it has more "bells and whistles" (more methods).

Here's an example showing how one class "decorates" the functionality of the one it wraps, and you can chain them up to keep decorating:

```
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("some.file")));
```